# While adding new data on the right side of a canvas, moving entire collection of points to the left

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a collection of data representing cloud height measurements every minute. As new data arrives, i want to add them on the right side of the canvas, moving the older data to the left. Is it possible to do this without using a specific charting library like canvasjs?
Some additional info to make things a little bit clearer. If the webpage is opened, data of the last 180 minutes are queried by an Ajax call. The data is in json format.

```
<style>
canvas {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
<fieldset>
<legend>Wolkenhöhen:</legend>
<div id="theCanvas">
    <canvas id="cloudCanvas" width="618" height="510" style="border:1px solid #ffffff;">
</canvas> 
</div>

<script>
    const blu = '#1c29cc';
    const wht = '#000000';
    const grn = '#008513';
    const ylo = '#e2ff28';
    const amb = '#9d4600';
    const red = '#9d0313';
    const gray = '#8f8481';
    const black = '#000000';
    var maxY = 510;
    var minY = 15;
    var minX = 10;
    var maxX = 600;

function plotGrit() {
    var c = document.getElementById("cloudCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(minX+20, minY);
    ctx.lineTo(minX+20, maxY-15);
    ctx.lineTo(maxX-15, maxY-15);
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#c9c9c9';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.font = "10px Arial";
};

function heightLine(hcld,ctxt) {
    var arr =      {"#9d4600":200,"#e2ff28":300,"#008513":700,"#000000":1500,"#1c29cc":2500};

    for (i=0; i<hcld; i+=2000) {
        ctxt.beginPath();
        ctxt.moveTo(minX+20, (480-480*i/hcld)+minY);
        ctxt.lineTo(maxX-15, (480-480*i/hcld)+minY);
        ctxt.strokeStyle = gray;
        ctxt.stroke();
        ctxt.closePath();
        ctxt.fillStyle = black;
        ctxt.fillText(i, minX-10, (480-480*i/hcld)+minY);
    }
    for(var key in arr)
    {
        var hgt = arr[key];
        ctxt.beginPath();
        ctxt.moveTo(minX+20, (480-480*hgt/hcld)+minY);
        ctxt.lineTo(maxX-15, (480-480*hgt/hcld)+minY);
        ctxt.strokeStyle = key;
        ctxt.stroke();
        ctxt.closePath();
    }
}

function timeLine(x,ctxt, col) {
    ctxt.beginPath();
    ctxt.moveTo(x, minY);
    ctxt.lineTo(x, maxY-15);
    ctxt.lineWidth = 1;
    ctxt.strokeStyle = col;
    ctxt.stroke();
    ctxt.closePath();
}

function cldDot(hgt, x, y ,ctxt) {
// plots a dot representing the measured cloud height
    if (hgt >= 2500) {
        col = blu;
    } else if (hgt >= 1500) {
        col = wht;
    } else if (hgt >= 700) {
        col = grn;
    } else if (hgt >= 300) {
        col = ylo;
    } else if (hgt >= 200) {
        col = amb;
    } else if ((hgt > 0) && (hgt < 200)) {
        col = red;
    }
    ctxt.fillStyle = col;
    ctxt.fillRect(x-3,y-3,3,3);
}

function fetchClouds() {
    var multiplier = 1/1000;
    var lcld = 400000;
    var hcld = 0;
    var X = minX+20;
    var c = document.getElementById("cloudCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "cloudQuery.php?tsteps=180",
        success: function(data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);      
            // Printing all the values from the resulting object
            for (var i in obj ) {
                cld = obj[i]['cldLyr_Service1'];
                cld2 = obj[i]['cldLyr_Service2'];
                cld3 = obj[i]['cldLyr_Service3'];
                if (cld < lcld && cld != 0) {
                    lcld = cld;
                }
                if (cld > hcld) {
                    hcld = cld;
                }
                var min = obj[i]['Time'].substring(3,5);
                if (min == 00) {
                    timeLine(X,ctx,black);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                    ctx.fillText(obj[i]['Time'], X-13, maxY-5);
                }
                if ((min % 10 == 0) && (min != 00)) {
                    timeLine(X,ctx,gray);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                    ctx.fillText(min, X-7, maxY-5);
                }
                cldDot(cld, X,(480-480*cld/hcld)+minY,ctx);
                if (cld2 > 0) {
                    cldDot(cld2, X,(480-480*cld2/hcld)+minY,ctx);
                }
                if (cld3 > 0) {
                    cldDot(cld3, X,(480-480*cld3/hcld)+minY,ctx);
                }
                X+=3;
            }
            heightLine(hcld,ctx);
            lcld = 0 + " ft";
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fillText(lcld, minX-10, maxY-15);
            hcld = hcld + " ft";
            ctx.fillText(hcld, minX-10, maxY-490);
        }
    }); 
};

fetchClouds();
plotGrit();

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(fetchClouds, 1000);
});

</script> 
</fieldset>
```

The result looks like
[image: Cloudheight diagram]

Comment: Hey Roedelproemm, welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure to add some details to your question, so others can reproduce the issue and help you as best as possible. Make sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this article about including Runnable JavaScript, CSS, and HTML Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets).

Comment: You should include this in your original post by editing it. Also, include some code so others can reproduce. What you are describing is a hypothetical case that is not concrete enough to work with.

Comment: A canvas is just that - it doesn't have structure so 'move to the left' isn't something you can do in the way you could with HTML elements. You'd need to clear the canvas and redraw the info in its new position. Please add code to your question showing how the canvas is drawn on.